# Error while using react-virtualized-select

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-redux

Trying to use 'react-virtualized-select' as per https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized-select

we are using require.js in our application **imported after getting it from npm and didn't the import css ....as mentioned here** https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized-select#simple-example

[image]

**Note : posting full code to make easy to understand context Please ignore any short coming's in rest of code as the error disappears if i remove the VirtualizedSelect tag**

```
    var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var VirtualizedSelect = require('react-virtualized-select');

module.exports = React.createClass({
    componentName: 'Search',
    getDefaultProps() {
        return {};
    },
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            error: false,
            authenticated: false,
            visible: true,
            data: null,
            showAccountSelection: false,
            selected: null,
            search: '',
            optionPartnerList: []

        };
    },
    componentDidMount () {
        var qS = queryString.parse(location.search);
        if (qS && qS.search) {
            this.setState({search: qS.search, visible: true});
        }

        this._unsubscribe = AppStore.listen(Utils.createRefluxComponentDispatcher(this));
    },
    componentDidUpdate: function () {
        if (this.refs.inputSearch) {
            this.refs.inputSearch.focus();
            this.refs.inputSearch.select()
        }
    },

    componentWillUnmount () {
        this._unsubscribe();
    },

render: function () {
        var self= this;
        if (!this.state.authenticated) {
            return null;
        }
        let componentDisabled = this.state.async ? true : false;
        let buttonIcon;
        let closeButton = AppStore.selectedAccount ?
            <a href="#" className="closebtn" onClick={this.closeNav}>&times;</a> :
            (<a key="-1" className="logout-link dropdown-item t-font" onClick={AppActions.logout} href="#">
                <i className="fa fa-sign-out m-r-10"></i>Logout</a>);

        let overlayStyle = {width: this.state.visible ? '100%' : '0px', display: this.state.visible ? 'block' : 'none', 'overflowX': 'hidden', 'overflowY': this.state.overlayOverflowY};
        if (this.state.visible) {
            AppActions.hideBodyScrollBar();
        } else {
            AppActions.showBodyScrollBar();
        }

        if (!this.state.async) {
            buttonIcon = <i className="fa fa-search"></i>
        } else {
            buttonIcon = <i className="fa fa-cog fix fa-spin"></i>
        }
        //TODO: refactor this make it css driven using flex box
        let style = {top: '37%'};
        if (this.state.data && Object.keys(this.state.data).length > 1) {
            style = {top: '10%'};
        }
        return (

            <div style={{float:'left'}} className="search-div">
                {this.searchIcon()}
                <div className="overlay" style={overlayStyle}>
                    {closeButton}
                    <div className="global-search center-content-wrapper" style={style}>
                        <form id="searchFormComponent" ref={function(){$('#searchFormComponent').show('fast')}}
                              className="global-search" onSubmit={this.handleClick} style={{height: '500px'}}>
                            {this.errorRender()}
                            <div className="f-row f-center">
                                <input id="searchbox" type="text" ref="inputSearch" className="form-control f-9 searchbox"
                                       placeholder="SEARCH FOR ACCOUNT" required
                                       style={{marginBottom:'1px'}} disabled={componentDisabled}
                                       defaultValue={this.state.search}>
                                </input>
                                <VirtualizedSelect
                                    options={self.optionPartnerList}
                                    onChange={(selectValue) => this.setState({ selectValue })}
                                    value={this.state.selectValue}
                                />
                                <button id="searchbutton" className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block t-font f-1"
                                        disabled={componentDisabled}
                                        onClick={this.handleClick}
                                        style={{ paddingLeft: '4px',paddingRight: '4px', fontSize:'1.1em',marginLeft:'4px'}}>
                                    {buttonIcon}
                                </button>
                                <SearchHint ref={"searchHint"} toggleOverlayStyle={this.toggleOverlayStyle}/>
                            </div>
                            <SearchAccountSelector data={this.state.search == ''? {}: this.state.data}/>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

getting this exception

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of `exports`.     at invariant (bundle.c81618e7.js:5333)     at instantiateReactComponent (bundle.c81618e7.js:27936)     at Object.updateChildren (bundle.c81618e7.js:17273)     at ReactDOMComponent._reconcilerUpdateChildren (bundle.c81618e7.js:23289)     at ReactDOMComponent._updateChildren (bundle.c81618e7.js:23393)     at ReactDOMComponent.updateChildren (bundle.c81618e7.js:23380)     at ReactDOMComponent._updateDOMChildren (bundle.c81618e7.js:19340)     at ReactDOMComponent.updateComponent (bundle.c81618e7.js:19154)     at ReactDOMComponent.receiveComponent (bundle.c81618e7.js:19116)     at Object.receiveComponent (bundle.c81618e7.js:24009)
```

Not able to find the mistake i made any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated please find my package.json entries

```
"react": "^15.6.2",
"react-dimensions": "^1.3.0",
"react-dom": "^15.6.2",
"react-virtualized-select": "3.1.0",
```

Comment: Usually that happens when you forget to export some component you've created. Have you checked that already? Also, if you could provide a little but more of code that would help.

Comment: can I see how you used the element in your component. Show more code

Comment: @BrunnoVodolaMartins thanks for the response ! as per the sample code in Git we need to import css like i mentioned which i didn't do ...do u think that's causing the issue ?

Comment: @user2359997 i don't think that the missing CSS files are the issue here. That would only make your components look unstyled. Could you please post the entire code of the component that sorrounds your `VirtualizedSelect`?

Comment: @BrunnoVodolaMartins added more code

Comment: @Onyekachi added more code

Comment: Try `var VirtualizedSelect = require('react-virtualized-select').default;`

Comment: yep adding .default fixed it thanks @MattHolland

Comment: Awesome! I'll add that as an answer.

Comment: @BrunnoVodolaMartins any thoughts on how can i add the css

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the line:

```
var VirtualizedSelect = require('react-virtualized-select');
```

Which needs to be changed to:

```
var VirtualizedSelect = require('react-virtualized-select').default;
```

The error message is because what's being imported isn't a React component, and seemingly has to do with the way that the `export default` in React Virtualized Select's source has been traspiled into ES5.

Comment: any thoughts on how to add the css as mentioned in the question

Comment: How are you bundling your JS source? The method in the docs there assumes you're using a particular webpack config (A similar setup to Create React App uses).

Comment: If all else fails you can add the CSS directly in your index.html file as normal `<link>` tags

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add the **render** method for the class component.

checkout the code below

```js
    var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var VirtualizedSelect = require('react-virtualized-select');

module.exports = React.createClass({
    componentName: 'Search',
    getDefaultProps() {
        return {};
    },
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            error: false,
            authenticated: false,
            visible: true,
            data: null,
            showAccountSelection: false,
            selected: null,
            search: '',
            optionPartnerList: []

        };
    },
    componentDidMount () {
        var qS = queryString.parse(location.search);
        if (qS && qS.search) {
            this.setState({search: qS.search, visible: true});
        }

        this._unsubscribe = AppStore.listen(Utils.createRefluxComponentDispatcher(this));
    },
    componentDidUpdate: function () {
        if (this.refs.inputSearch) {
            this.refs.inputSearch.focus();
            this.refs.inputSearch.select()
        }
    },

    componentWillUnmount () {
        this._unsubscribe();
    }
   render() {
     return (

            <div style={{float:'left'}} className="search-div">
                {this.searchIcon()}
                <div className="overlay" style={overlayStyle}>
                    {closeButton}
                    <div className="global-search center-content-wrapper" style={style}>
                        <form id="searchFormComponent" ref={function(){$('#searchFormComponent').show('fast')}}
                              className="global-search" onSubmit={this.handleClick} style={{height: '500px'}}>
                            {this.errorRender()}
                            <div className="f-row f-center">
                                <input id="searchbox" type="text" ref="inputSearch" className="form-control f-9 searchbox"
                                       placeholder="SEARCH FOR ACCOUNT" required
                                       style={{marginBottom:'1px'}} disabled={componentDisabled}
                                       defaultValue={this.state.search}>
                                </input>
                                <VirtualizedSelect
                                    options={self.optionPartnerList}
                                    onChange={(selectValue) => this.setState({ selectValue })}
                                    value={this.state.selectValue}
                                />
                                <button id="searchbutton" className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block t-font f-1"
                                        disabled={componentDisabled}
                                        onClick={this.handleClick}
                                        style={{ paddingLeft: '4px',paddingRight: '4px', fontSize:'1.1em',marginLeft:'4px'}}>
                                    {buttonIcon}
                                </button>

                            </div>

                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
   }
    }
});
```

Comment: I had render before too

Comment: any thoughts on how to add css

Comment: your custom css ?